# Multiple sessions of the Distributor Agent running in SQL Server Replication Monitor

Tags: sql-server-2016, database-replication, transactional-replication

I've configured replication in SQL Server (Developer Edition) using three local servers: `SVR1`, which has a publication; `SVR2`, which acts as the distributor server; and `SVR3`, which has two push subscribers and one pull subscriber. It works perfectly, replicating data from the publisher to the subscribers with no issues.

When monitoring replication using the `Replication Monitoring program`, I've noticed that in `Sessions of the Distribution Agent` (`Distributor To Subscriber History`) for any subscription, it shows at least two sessions running.

I've stopped all jobs (`Log-Readers` and `Distributors`) and even stopped the `SQL Server Agent` service on all servers, expecting all sessions to complete, but one session remained running.

In the following images of a push subscription, one session was completed and one remains running (two sessions were running before stopping job and `SQL Server Agent` service).

**Job completed after stopping job**

[image: one session completed due to stopped job]

**One session remains running after stop job and stop SQL Server Agent service**
[image: one session running even with SQL Server Agent service stopped]

Is this something expected?
I thought this session was related to the running job... If not related to running job, what are these sessions actually related to?